# How to install and run VB.NET Application to another computer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I had this problem on how to install my vb.net application i published a while ago. After i published the vb.net project, i copied the file and tried to install to another computer but, this error was shown.

```
Cannot download the application. The application is missing required files. Contact application vendor for assistance.
```

Can anybody help me please.

I need to run this application to other computers connected to my PC as the database server.

[Just-In-Time Error when running the application to another computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZD3Q.png)

Comment: Do you use ClickOnce to install your application?

Comment: Yes,. what's the effect if just in case "ClickOnce" is the option?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when one or more of the files listed in the application manifest cannot be found on the server. I would suggest you open the application manifest in a text editor and verify that you have uploaded all the deployment's dependent files and also check manually if the ClickOnce Install Source is correct.

If you need more information for this case then [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229001.aspx)

Comment: how will i do it?